# How to populate form with JSON data using data store?

Tags: javascript, json, forms, extjs4, datastore

How to populate form with JSON data using data store? How are the textfields connected with store, model?

```
Ext.define('app.formStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
   {name: 'naziv', type:'string'},
   {name: 'oib', type:'int'},
   {name: 'email', type:'string'}
]
});

var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
model: 'app.formStore',
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url : 'app/myJson.json',
    reader:{ 
        type:'json'                     
    }
},
autoLoad:true   
});

Ext.onReady(function() {


var testForm = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
                    width: 500,
                    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                    title: 'testForm',
                    waitMsgTarget: true,
                    fieldDefaults: {
                        labelAlign: 'right',
                        labelWidth: 85,
                        msgTarget: 'side'
                    },
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'fieldset',
                        title: 'Contact Information',
                        items: [{
                                xtype:'textfield',
                                fieldLabel: 'Name',
                                name: 'naziv'
                            }, {
                                xtype:'textfield',
                                fieldLabel: 'oib',
                                name: 'oib'
                            }, {
                                xtype:'textfield',
                                fieldLabel: 'mail',
                                name: 'email'
                        }]
                    }]

            });

    testForm.getForm().loadRecord(app.formStore);
 });
```

JSON

```
[
    {"naziv":"Lisa", "oib":"2545898545", "email":"lisa@simpson.com"}        
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The field names of your model and form **should match**. Then you can load the form using `loadRecord()`. For example:

```
var record = Ext.create('XYZ',{
    name: 'Abc',
    email: 'abc@abc.com'
});
formpanel.getForm().loadRecord(record);
```

or, get the values from already loaded store.

Comment: @Abdel - it says "naziv" is not defined

Comment: testForm.getForm().load({url : 'app/myJson.json'}); returbs POST error

Comment: @Ingol, I wonder if you ever read the API documentation after reading my answer. check the syntax of the `loadRecord()` : http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.form.Basic

Comment: if you are using `load()` why are you using POST? you should set method: 'GET' .. the default value is POST.. again read the API

Comment: @Abdel - the API says (record : Ext.data.Model The record to load), so why is this wrong? testForm.getForm().loadRecord(naziv,oib,email);

Comment: there is only 1 argument(the model) and you are passing 3 arguments!

Comment: @Abdel-sorry, i am new to this, when i try this testForm.getForm().loadRecord(app.formStore); i get no errors but no loading the data into the form!

Comment: the formStore is not of the type `Model`. your formStore will be of type `Store`. you need to get your record out of the store. Since you have only one record (as per the above json) you can use formStore.getAt(0) to get the record. NOTE: Your model specified in store and form should match

Answer (score 3):

The answer of Abdel Olakara works great. But if you want to populate without the use of a store you can also do it like:

```
var record = {
      data : {
         group : 'Moody Blues',
         text  : 'One of the greatest bands'
      }
};
formpanel.getForm().loadRecord(record);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Ext Direct methods. This way you can implement very nice and clean all operations: edit, delete, etc.